# How do print out information from GET request in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this problem that is taking up too much of my development time. I have researched this problem a lot and it has now gotten me to here.

I'm making a GET request from a service. The GET request is being called from a controller.

Here is the service that makes the GET request, `ajaxSrvc.js`:

```
app.service('ajaxSrvc', ['$log', 'Constants', '$http', '$q', 
    function($log, Constants, $http, $q) {
        this.getAllTasks = function() {
            var defer = $q.defer();

            var url = 'http://localhost:9998/tasks';
            $http.get(url, {cache: 'true'})
                .success(function(data) {
                    defer.resolve(data);
                });

                return defer.promise;
        };
    }
]);
```

That request is invoked from this controller, `tasksCtrl.js`:

```
app.controller('tasksCtrl', ["$log", "$scope", "Constants","$location", "ajaxSrvc",
    function($log, $scope, Constants, $location, ajaxSrvc) {
        var someData = null;
        ajaxSrvc.getAllTasks().then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            someData = data;
        });

        console.log(someData); // This is printing NULL
    }
]);
```

The problem arises when I try to print out `someData`, it prints as `NULL` instead of containing information from the `GET` request.

How do I get around this?

Comment: I don't know angular that well but, ignoring that, you need to wait until the ajax call returns. You are printing it immediately after the request has been made. Put the log statement inside the callback.

Comment: Does your log statement `console.log(data)` print out the expected result?

Comment: You can't expect Async call to work in synchronus way as you thought, you can get data inside ajax call success, which would be inside `.then` function..

Comment: @yuxhuang yes I am getting the expected result

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to wait to the async function to finish. When you do `console.log(someData)` The code is still loading the data inside the async function. You can add a function call inside the `.then` function, that will execute after the load finish.

If `console.log(data)` is returning the expected value you should do something like this:

```
app.controller('tasksCtrl', ["$log", "$scope", "Constants","$location", "ajaxSrvc",
    function($log, $scope, Constants, $location, ajaxSrvc) {
        var someData = null;
        ajaxSrvc.getAllTasks().then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            someData = data;
            callWhenFinish();
        });

        function callWhenFinish(){
            console.log(someData);
        }
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because this is a asynchronous action, so basically the console.log(someData) is getting called before you actually get the data. It will never work.

Answer (score 1):

Since **getAllTasks()** is a promise , **someData will log first before the promise is ready**.. So instead of assigning your callback data to **someData** within the **callback scope** , just pass **data** to a function instead then do whatever from there..

**Example :**

```
 ajaxSrvc.getAllTasks().then(function(data) {

               doSomethingWithData(data);
        });
```

//Then

```
$scope.doSomethingWithData = function(data){

      $scope.someData = data;

      console.log($scope.someData);

}
```

Hope this helps.